# Boost Spirit parser with inherited attributes - simple example won't compile

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit

I'm trying to write a parser for a C-like language with boost::spirit that uses inherited attributes to transfer information about variable scope.  For instance, "namespace a { var b }" would pass "a" as an attribute to the parser for "var b".

I'm having trouble getting a basic parser using inherited attributes to compile this code:

```
#ifndef CPARSER_DEF_HPP
#define CPARSER_DEF_HPP

#include <string>

#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>

namespace encoding = boost::spirit::ascii;
using boost::spirit::unused_type;
using boost::spirit::qi::rule;

template <typename Iterator>
struct cparser : boost::spirit::qi::grammar<
                    Iterator,
                    std::string(std::string),
                    encoding::space_type
                    >
{
    rule<Iterator, std::string(std::string), encoding::space_type> start;
    rule<Iterator, std::string(std::string), encoding::space_type> sym_list;

    cparser() :
        cparser::base_type(start)
    {
        sym_list         = encoding::string(boost::spirit::qi::_r1);
        start            = sym_list(boost::spirit::qi::_r1);
    }

};

#endif
```

This parser is instantiated in main() with `cparser<std::string::const_iterator> parser`.

I believe this parser should accept a std::string as its inherited attribute, parse input matching this string, then return the string as a synthesised attribute.  This example code does not compile, and I cannot figure out why.  I have been compiling with GCC and Clang with C++11 enabled.  The output from either compiler is huge (approx. 1000 lines), and I cannot make any sense of it.  Is there a problem with the use of `boost::spirit::qi::_r1`?  A problem with `std::string(std::string)` in the rule declarations?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I haven't tried your code but, when you say GCC you mean something like `gcc --std=c++11` or `g++ --std=c++11`? You should be using the second one.

Comment: Sorry for not being more specific in the question, I am using this command: `g++ -std=c++11 src/simple_cparser.cpp -c -o objs/simple_cparser.o`, and the same command with clang++ substituted for g++.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've tried to construct an example [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fdfa3eb466e75696). I'm not sure I've faced the same issues you have(since you didn't provide a way to reproduce them) but I think there were two different problems: The first one, very common, is that PhoenixV2 does not work with "modern compilers" since the breaking change in Boost 1.52 that made `BOOST_RESULT_OF_USE_DECLTYPE` the default. 
There are two ways to solve this (at least with the clang version that coliru uses) either use V3 by defining `BOOST_SPIRIT_USE_PHOENIX_V3`(this is what I would recommend, and I think it should be the default) or return the result_of protocol to the behaviour V2 expects by defining `BOOST_RESULT_OF_USE_TR1`. The second problem, of which I'm not as familiarized so take this with a grain of salt or simply wait for an answer from "someone" more experienced, is that it seems that you can't pass string literals directly as an inherited attribute, you need to pass them as a string (using phx::val("foo") also seems to work).

Short version: Define BOOST_SPIRIT_USE_PHOENIX_V3 and pass your inherited attributes as a std::string not as a string literal.

Comment: Thanks, defining BOOST_SPIRIT_USE_PHOENIX_V3 and passing a std::string rather than const char* as the inherited attribute were the only changes required.  Defining BOOST_RESULT_OF_USE_TR1 also works, but I will use BOOST_SPIRIT_USE_PHOENIX_V3 as recommended.

Comment: I wonder if the inherited attribute needs to be a std::string rather than a const char* because it is implicitly converted to another type by Spirit.  The compiler will perform one implicit conversion (std::string to Spirit internal type or const char* to std::string), but not two.  This is purely a guess, but there can be no harm in being more specific about the type of the attribute.

Comment: [This thread in the mailing list](http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/Novice-problem-td4658183.html) shows the same problem with inherited attributes and string literals, and sehe (A.K.A. "someone" more experienced) suggests another approach (that atm only works on g++ and clang++) and that is to add a `+` in front of your literal, forcing it to decay from `const char[N]` to `const char*`. [The same example in my answer with this approach](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2148e4458e9cc738).