# Boost.Spirit mini_xml2.cpp example could not be compiled by C++11, Boost 1.55

Tags: c++, boost, c++11, boost-spirit

c++0x compiler fails to compile boost.spirit example [mini_xml2.cpp](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/spirit/example/qi/mini_xml2.cpp) (and no errors from not c++0x compiler)

```
$> c++ -std=c++0x mini_xml2.cpp (errors)
$> c++ mini_xml2.cpp (no errors)
```

The error log is placed [here](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/attachment/ticket/9509/compile.2.log). I suspect that problem is related to nonterminal attributes (lines 159-163), but I could be wrong.

- c++ version (Ubuntu / Linaro 4.8.1-10ubuntu9) 4.8.1
- Boost version 1.55

I've created [issue](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/9509) at the boost tracker, but have no answer.

Does anybody have the same errors?

**Solved**: I found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20440939/504346).

```
// Add this macro
#define BOOST_SPIRIT_USE_PHOENIX_V3
```

Comment: Not to be pedantic, but that is the g++ version, not the c++ version. g++ is **a** c++ compiler, of which there are many.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As indicated, on modern compilers you will actually need to use Phoenix V3, as Phoenix V2 relies on the *old* result-of protocol, which in newer versions of boost libraries just isn't always included anymore.

Additionally on some compilers (AFAIK at least clang) the BOOST_RESULT_OF_USE_DECLTYPE approach is enabled by default, which may cause the supporting libraries to omit the (more costly) TR1 result-of protocol.

The good news is, after we **[signaled this on the user list](http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/Json-parser-tp4642901p4655166.html)** as a recurring stumbling block, the official decision is here:

> **[Farewell Phoenix-2](http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/Boost-Spirit-Farewell-Phoenix-2-td4656504.html)** Dec 14, 2013; 3:38am (Joel de Guzman)
> (also [blog post](http://boost-spirit.com/home/2013/12/13/farewell-phoenix-2/))
>
> Boost C++... After more than a decade, I finally retired Phoenix-2 from the 
>   Boost Spirit code base. I feel sad. It's like farewell to a good friend. Onwards 
>   to Phoenix-3.

That's just 7 days ago :)

So in the (near) future this problem will have been resolved.

Comment: "So in the (near) future this problem will have been resolved." and with it 3/4 of the questions in this tag :).

Comment: Okay, 3/4 may be a stretch, but yeah, quoting my mailing list post: _"I can't keep track of the number of times where PhoenixV3  has solved
people's issues with Spirit. It's overwhelmingly recurring"_. (Also, you're fast!)