# Calculate expression string consists of keys in a std::map

Tags: c++, dictionary, boost

I have c++ std::map object like

```
std::map<std::string, int> data = {{"a",1},{"b",2}};
```

And I have a string expression consists of the keys in this map:

```
"(a%2)+2*((b-2)%2)"
```

All I want to do is to calculate the value of this expression, and the return type should be `int`. Is there a way to do this? Maybe the `boost` package could be helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[ExprTk](http://partow.net/programming/exprtk/index.html) seems to be what you are looking for, seems simple to use and only requires `#include "exprtk.hpp"`.

This can be done using `boost`, as show in the [answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28100863/how-to-parse-a-mathematical-expression-with-boostspirit-and-bind-it-to-a-funct).

Comment: Thanks a lot, ExprTk is helpful:)