# Boost spirit karma example fails compilation with -std=c++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost

I have this curious problem on both GCC and CLANG on two different machines. The Karma example from:

```
http://svn.boost.org/svn/boost/trunk/libs/spirit/example/karma/escaped_string.cpp
```

... compiles perferctly well with default standard settings, e.g.:

```
c++ -O2 -pipe -march=native escaped_string.cpp -o escaped_string
```

... but failes with an error message in excess of 100 KB with std=c++11:

```
c++ -O2 -pipe -march=native -std=c++11 escaped_string.cpp -o escaped_string
```

Of course, the way I found this out was by using the example code in my project which is compiled with c++11 and losing some hours in wondering what blew up :)

Boost version is 1.55. The entire error message is pasted at http://pastebin.com/4L6MdYFx .

Is this expected / well known? Will Boost blow up in other libraries when using std=c++11 ? Is there a way around it?

Comment: I can confirm that I've had Spirit qi/karma working satisfactorily with `clang` and `-std=c+++11` - it's the default state of affairs on MacOSX development hosts.  Looking at the error logs you posted (hint: clang does a much better job with them) - it looks as if it's actually `boost::fusion` rather than karma per se. 

I wonder whether your boost installation is correctly configured?

(BTW: For fun, try running the clang static analyser over the program once you've got it to build. You might need to make several cups of coffee whilst it runs).

Comment: You need to define `BOOST_SPIRIT_USE_PHOENIX_V3` before the inclusion of the Karma headers. I believe this will be solved whenever 1.56 is released.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20721486/boost-spirit-mini-xml2-cpp-example-coud-not-be-compiled-by-c11-boost-1-55